# Detecting if the system time doesn't correspond to system timezone [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I have a particular system configuration where my timezone is setted at (UTC-03:00) but I configured the system time to an hour after (e.g: Originally my time using the timezone must be 14:41, but I updated to 15:41).

What I want to know if there is a way using any library to know that the time is not correlated with the timezone.

Other solution could be to resolve the time using **moment** or other library returning the time using the system timezone and not the system time.

I tired using **Date** or **moment** with **moment-timezone** with no luck.

E.g:

System Time: 15:46 (+1 Hour configured manually)

Timezone Time: 14:46 (This should be the hour if isn't updated)

```
moment()  //result Wed Nov 17 2021 15:46:19 GMT-0300
```

What I want is

```
moment().someFunc()  //result Wed Nov 17 2021 14:46:19 GMT-0300
// Could be a function, property, just a difference to use it in order 
//to compare with other date that comes from the server
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to get the utc date time (with `moment().utc()`) the result is your time less utcOffset and there isn't somthing about that in the documentation, so I think there isn't a way to do what do you want.

an alternative is to get the time from a external server like code bellow, but I hope for you that someone else know a way better

```js
async function myTzTime() {
  const timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
  const { data: { datetime } = {} } = await axios.get(`http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/${timezone}`);
  

  console.log('--->', datetime)
}

myTzTime();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.24.0/axios.min.js"></script>
```